# ocsigenserver.opt fails on startup with Unix.ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen, econnrefused

My ocsigen server has been working fine for a while, but just as I'm about to show it off to someone, it spews this on startup and then exits with failure:

```
ocsigenserver.opt: ocsipersist:dbm: Cannot connect to Ocsidbm. Will continue without persistent session support. Error message is: Connection refused in connect() .Have a look at the logs to see if there is an error message from the Ocsidbm process.
ocsigenserver.opt: ocsigen:main: Fatal - While loading /home/unhammer/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ocsigenserver/extensions/ocsipersist-dbm.cmxs: Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Start up ocsigenserver.opt with -V (very verbose), if it says something like

```
ocsigenserver.opt: ocsipersist:dbm: Launching a new Ocsidbm process: /home/unhammer/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ocsigenserver/extensions/ocsidbm.opt on directory /usr/local/var/data/PROJECT/ocsipersist.
```

then you could try `rm -f /usr/local/var/data/PROJECT/ocsipersist/socket` (or, if you have no important data there, even `rm -rf /usr/local/var/data/PROJECT`). This worked for me.

Comment: yes. I don't know if there's a way to avoid the problem in the first place though.

Comment: I confirm, it worked for me! Saved me lots of trouble +9000